# Is there a better way to create events in java?

Tags: java, events, interface

Unlike C#, Java doesn't have something called an event. If I want to create an event, I need to create an interface first:

```
public interface MyEventListner {
    void onMyEvent (object sender);
}
```

and in the class that raises the event, I write:

```
public class MyRaiser {
    private ArrayList<MyEventListner> listners;
    public void addMyEventHandler (MyEventListner listener) {
        this.listners.add (listner);
    }
    private void raiseMyEvent () {
        for (MyEventListner listener : listners) {
            listener.onMyEvent ();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is just a simplified version. I also need to check whether something is null and other stuff.

Therefore, I want to ask whether this is the *best* way to do an event. If this is not, please tell me.

Comment: More common name is callback :) u register a back call method via interface raised from caller. This is the right way all android api is made of callbacks eg listeners